# PouchDB / Ionic 1 / CouchDB - architecture recommendation

Tags: ionic-framework, architecture, couchdb, pouchdb

I have a multi-user single-page mobile app developed with `Ionic 1`, `PouchDB` and `CouchDB`. User's management is achieved with `SuperLogin`.

I would like to add a feature **computing a score** (something similar to the score in the **Waze** app) for each user based on his current data, and keeping a track of the former values of that score every past day.

I am wondering about the best way to implement this.

About my app:

it should be able to work offline, and then sync with the server when online (this is why I am using PouchDB and CouchDB, working great so far). So on the server, I have one CouchDB database per user, storing his own data
on the server. The PouchDB database in the app is syncing with the one of the user on the server.

I am considering various options for the score, but none of them really satisfy me, so your advice would be welcome (possibly for yet another option)

**Option 1**: The score is computed in the app by the Ionic code. The result is stored as a local database object, with a date and a score value. This happens whenever the user changes its data. As the DB is synced with the server, these scores are updated in the server too. However, if some days the user does not use the application, the score won't be computed for these days. More over, if the user runs the app on 2 different devices, and update some data on one of them, this will make the score recomputed locally, then propagated on the server. When the changed data propagate to the server and to the other device, this will trigger a new score computation on this other device, and might lead to conflicts on the score object in the server. Finally, if at some point in time, I want to change the way of computing the score, the value given to each user will depend on whether he has upgraded to the latest app version.

**Option 2**: have a server-side process that triggers every day, and compute each user's score by connecting to each user's DB on the server, reading its data, computing the corresponding score, and storing it (date+value) back in the server DB. This option looks cleaner to me, but it would require further developments, and an additional process to maintain and keep alive on the server. And if the user inputs data to the application while not connected to the internet, the score will not be updated in the app until he gets connected again (which would cause the server process to recompute the score, and propagate it back to the app through CouchDB sync)

**Option 3**: have some kind of "stored procedure" in the CouchDB server, triggering every time related data change, in charge of computing the score of each user. But I don't think this is doable with CouchDB.

So how would you do this score computation please??
Many thanks!